# Java- HashMap.get returns null when it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, null, hashmap

I am using a HashMap to link some strings to integers, which are then used to index a list.
The strings I am using in .get() are passed to a method, from an android spinner, and are definitely correct as I outputted them to the log, and they match those in the HashMap.
However, calling .get with one of these strings returns null, and subsequently leads to the app force closing when I attempt to use the null integer in a calculation.

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> valuesOfAngleUnits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void setValuesOfAngleUnits(HashMap<String, Integer> valuesOfAngleUnits) {
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Arc minute", 0);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Arc second", 1);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Degree", 2);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Gon", 3);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Grad", 4);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Mil (Nato)", 5);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Mil (Soviet Union)", 6);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Octant", 7);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Quadrant", 8);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Radian", 9);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Revolution", 10);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Sextant", 11);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Sign", 12);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Turn", 13);
}

List<Double> convertToArcSeconds = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 0.1666667, 0.000046, 0.0166667, 0.18519, 0.18519, 0.296296, 0.277778, 0.291667, 0.00037, 0.000185, 0.000291, 0.000046, 0.000278, 0.000556, 0.000046));


public void calculateConversion(String inputSpinner, String outputSpinner, Float userInput){
    Float output = new Float(0.0);
    String Tag = "Input collected";
    Log.v(Tag, "The input data type is " + inputSpinner + ". The output data type is " + outputSpinner + ", and the user input is " + userInput);
    Integer numericalValueOfInputSpinner = valuesOfAngleUnits.get(inputSpinner);
    Log.v(Tag, "The numerical value of the spinner is " + numericalValueOfInputSpinner);
    Float ArcSecondValue = new Float(userInput * convertToArcSeconds.get(numericalValueOfInputSpinner));
    String Tag2 = "ArcSecondValueFound";
    Log.v(Tag2, "The arc second value is " + ArcSecondValue);

}
```

The code above sets up a hashmap and a list, and shows you the method being used.

```
    06-22 21:23:34.113    3728-3728/? V/Input collected﹕ The input data type is Arc minute. The output data type is Arc minute, and the user input is 7645.0
06-22 21:23:34.113    3728-3728/? V/Input collected﹕ The numerical value of the spinner is null
06-22 21:23:34.113    3728-3728/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-22 21:23:34.114    3728-3728/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.anapp.tpb.sidebarproject, PID: 3728
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
            at com.anapp.tpb.sidebarproject.MainActivity.calculateConversion(MainActivity.java:78)
            at com.anapp.tpb.sidebarproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:100)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-22 21:23:34.114    1224-1388/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.anapp.tpb.sidebarproject/.MainActivity
```

Above is the logcat output. The first two lines show that the correct strings have been passed to the method, along with a float.
However, the numerical value is null.
I don't understand why this is happening, as the string "Arc minute" is in the valuesOfAngleUnits HashMap.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the `setValuesOfAngleUnits` method somewhere? (prior to trying to get the value from the Map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the problem :

```
HashMap<String, Integer> valuesOfAngleUnits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void setValuesOfAngleUnits(HashMap<String, Integer> valuesOfAngleUnits) {
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Arc minute", 0);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Arc second", 1);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Degree", 2);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Gon", 3);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Grad", 4);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Mil (Nato)", 5);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Mil (Soviet Union)", 6);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Octant", 7);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Quadrant", 8);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Radian", 9);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Revolution", 10);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Sextant", 11);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Sign", 12);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Turn", 13);
}
```

You are initializing the local HashMap passed to the method, which may not be the same as the instance variable having the same name.

Change it to :

```
public void setValuesOfAngleUnits() {
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Arc minute", 0);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Arc second", 1);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Degree", 2);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Gon", 3);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Grad", 4);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Mil (Nato)", 5);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Mil (Soviet Union)", 6);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Octant", 7);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Quadrant", 8);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Radian", 9);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Revolution", 10);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Sextant", 11);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Sign", 12);
    valuesOfAngleUnits.put("Turn", 13);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right; the problem was simply that I was not calling setValuesOfAngleUnits, meaning that valuesOfAngleUnits was empty.